# Crash when displaying keyboard

Tags: swiftui

This problem does not occur when the application is initially installed, but appears after a period of use (few days), and once it appears Whether it is TextField or TextEditor or even UITextField will crash every time, unless the app is deleted and reinstalled

Apparently, I did not do any Array-related operations myself when displaying the keyboard and editing the text

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem, or is there a workaround?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYLzL.jpg)

console:

```
2022-01-13 15:50:30.677412+0800 βSimplr[2108:295455] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x180b590fc 0x199393d64 0x180c62564 0x180aef0e4 0x183529438 0x18344beb8 0x1830810b8 0x1831f9820 0x1834899f8 0x183ca2c94 0x1833c7638 0x183ca2968 0x18322c8e0 0x1830f760c 0x18310bd80 0x1848e03a4 0x101bba3b4 0x101bca898 0x180b11d84 0x180acbf5c 0x180adf468 0x19c66a38c 0x183481088 0x1831ff958 0x1887987a4 0x1886c7928 0x1886a90c0 0x1002fe4d4 0x1002fe580 0x1019d5aa4)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

call stack:

```
[
"0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180b59110 16FAA70C-278C-3561-859E-CEC407C2DC7C + 626960",
"1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000199393d64 objc_exception_throw + 60",
"2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180c62564 16FAA70C-278C-3561-859E-CEC407C2DC7C + 1713508",
"3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180aef0e4 16FAA70C-278C-3561-859E-CEC407C2DC7C + 192740",
"4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000183529438 CD7F7BA2-A2C6-3727-AFF6-9BAAB60CC6AB + 6038584",
"5   UIKitCore                           0x000000018344beb8 CD7F7BA2-A2C6-3727-AFF6-9BAAB60CC6AB + 5131960",
"6   UIKitCore                           0x00000001830810b8 CD7F7BA2-A2C6-3727-AFF6-9BAAB60CC6AB + 1155256",
"7   UIKitCore                           0x00000001831f9820 CD7F7BA2-A2C6-3727-AFF6-9BAAB60CC6AB + 2697248",
"8   UIKitCore                           0x00000001834899f8 CD7F7BA2-A2C6-3727-AFF6-9BAAB60CC6AB + 5384696",
"9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000183ca2c94 CD7F7BA2-A2C6-3727-AFF6-9BAAB60CC6AB + 13876372",
"10  UIKitCore                           0x00000001833c7638 CD7F7BA2-A2C6-3727-AFF6-9BAAB60CC6AB + 4589112",
"11  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183ca2968 CD7F7BA2-A2C6-3727-AFF6-9BAAB60CC6AB + 13875560",
"12  UIKitCore                           0x000000018322c8e0 CD7F7BA2-A2C6-3727-AFF6-9BAAB60CC6AB + 2906336",
"13  UIKitCore                           0x00000001830f760c CD7F7BA2-A2C6-3727-AFF6-9BAAB60CC6AB + 1639948",
"14  UIKitCore                           0x000000018310bd80 CD7F7BA2-A2C6-3727-AFF6-9BAAB60CC6AB + 1723776",
"15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001848e03a4 0594369D-11DD-39D9-A981-74984F490C0C + 824228",
"16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010428e3b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20",
"17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010429e898 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1224",
"18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180b11d84 16FAA70C-278C-3561-859E-CEC407C2DC7C + 335236",
"19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180acbf5c 16FAA70C-278C-3561-859E-CEC407C2DC7C + 48988",
"20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180adf468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600",
"21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000019c66a38c GSEventRunModal + 164",
"22  UIKitCore                           0x0000000183481088 CD7F7BA2-A2C6-3727-AFF6-9BAAB60CC6AB + 5349512",
"23  UIKitCore                           0x00000001831ff958 UIApplicationMain + 2092",
"24  SwiftUI                             0x00000001887987a4 06855417-78D5-3EED-9D8D-0ED99095DF31 + 2340772",
"25  SwiftUI                             0x00000001886c7928 06855417-78D5-3EED-9D8D-0ED99095DF31 + 1485096",
"26  SwiftUI                             0x00000001886a90c0 $s7SwiftUI3AppPAAE4mainyyFZ + 128",
"27  βSimplr                             0x0000000102a3e018 $s0010Simplr_vxe9ReaderAppV5$mainyyFZ + 40",
"28  βSimplr                             0x0000000102a3e0c4 main + 12",
"29  dyld                                0x0000000104159aa4 start + 520"
]
```